# appengine's deleting index is taking long time

Tags: google-app-engine

I had about 180 indexes and removed 150 of these indexes from index.yaml and run command vacuum_index. But the 'datastore index' page is still showing the these indexes in 'deleting' status. I've called the command about 20 hours ago.

is it OK? or need to do something to delete them?

Comment: The Datastore statistics page shows that total number of entities are 76,000 and size of all entities are 577 MB.
And after 10 days later, it's still in 'deleting' status. :(

Comment: you need to file a production issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue

Comment: Robert, That was your right, I've created a production issue, then they deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the FAQ](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/index_building.html):

> Q: Why do my indexes stay Building or Deleting for long periods of
> time?
>
> A: In the past, this often happened because worker shards were too
> large to be completed within the lease period. To address this, we
> first increased the lease period. Now, we split individual tablets
> into shards. Index building can still take some time, but it's
> considerably faster than it was before.